# Как очистить базу данных, а после этого вставить данные с помощью одного запроса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Работаю с **sqlite3 на Python**, мне необходимо заменить данные нескольких строчек. Единственный метод который подходит это удаление всех данных из базы с последующим заполнением, однако у меня не получается все объединить в один запрос.

DDL базы:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    name     TEXT     NOT NULL,
    date     DATETIME NOT NULL,
    priority INT      NOT NULL,
    done     BOOLEAN  NOT NULL
);
```

Вот 2 запроса: `DELETE FROM TEST` и `INSERT INTO TEST(name, date, priority, done) VALUES('r', '12', 1, 'False')`.

Comment: *мне необходимо заменить данные нескольких строчек. Единственный метод который подходит это удаление всех данных из базы* - совершенно не очевидно. Так же как и не несущая никакого смысла фраза *у меня не получается все объединить в один запрос* Попробуйте понятно сформулировать проблему

Comment: Для изменения данных в некоторых строчках лучше написать обычный update запрос. Убивать все таблицу как то очень странно. 
Если ты хочешь сделать это руками то:
insert into TEST (name, date,priority,done)
VALUES('r', '12', 1, 'False'), ('r', '12', 1, 'False'),('r', '12', 1, 'False'),('r', '12', 1, 'False');

Но лучше использовать Update

Comment: Почитай https://tinyurl.com/yyo9esqz